# Issue with percent signs in luacode (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: directlua

My example doesn't work at this location `string.find(s:sub(1, 1), "%a")`.

How to fix it?

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf-8
%============================================================================================
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic]{Courier New}
%==========================================================
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{kerning=russian}
\usepackage{luacode}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addtosort#1#2{%
    \directlua{%
    tbl=tbl or {}%
    table.insert(tbl, {abbr="\luaescapestring{#1}", desc="\luaescapestring{#2}"})%
}%
}

\newcommand{\key}[2]{#1\addtosort{#1}{#2}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\printsorted{%
\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{%
tblru=tbl or {}

local function ChangingLatinStr(s)
if string.find(s:sub(1, 1), "%a") then
    return "ЯЯЯ" .. s
else return s
end
end

table.sort(tbl, function (a,b) return (ChangingLatinStr(a.abbr) < ChangingLatinStr(b.abbr)) end)

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    tex.print("\string\\printkw{" .. n.abbr .. "}{" .. n.desc .. "}")
end
}%
\endgroup
}


\newcommand\printkw[2]{\textbf{#1}~-- #2.\\}

\newcommand{\printkey}{%
\typeout{KW: NOW SHOWING}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}

\noindent\printsorted
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\key{ЯНАО}{Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ}.


\key{LED}{Light emitting diode}.

\key{FET}{Field effect transistor}.

\key{БД}{База данных}.

\key{ЛПР}{Лицо, принимающее решения}.

\key{XML}{Extensible markup language}.

\printkey

\end{document}
```

Comment: You'll have to change the category code of `%`, as it's the comment-character on the TeX-level. You can do that with `\catcode\`\%=12` before `\def\printsorted` (you'll want to remove the `%` from behind the opening brace of the definition and move `\directlua` into the same line). After the definition you can make `%` the comment character again with `\catcode\`\%=14`.

Comment: \catcode`\%=12
\def\printsorted{%
\directlua{%
tblru=tbl or {}

local function ChangingLatinStr(s)
if string.find(s:sub(1, 1), "%a") then
 return "ЯЯЯ" .. s
else return s
end
end

table.sort(tbl, function (a,b) return (ChangingLatinStr(a.abbr) < ChangingLatinStr(b.abbr)) end)

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
 tex.print("\string\\printkw{" .. n.abbr .. "}{" .. n.desc .. "}")
end
}}
\catcode`\%=14
This does not work, @Skillmon.

Comment: you are loading `luacode` package that provides commands specifcally designed to address this issue by normalising catcodes, but then do not use the package, and use the luatex primitive `\directua` so you have to manage catcodes yourself (or use `\@percentchar`)

Comment: I tried different examples, but none worked for me.
@David Carlisle.

Comment: Why is `%a` necessary? Just curious on my part.

Comment: I find all lines with the first English letter. Maybe there is an easier way?
@projetmbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrelated to lua you need to change catcodes outside the definition, inside is too late as the % has already been seen as a comment.

Also having made `%` not a comment you can not comment out ends of lines using it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic]{Courier New}
%==========================================================
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{kerning=russian}
\usepackage{luacode}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addtosort#1#2{%
    \directlua{%
    tbl=tbl or {}%
    table.insert(tbl, {abbr="\luaescapestring{#1}", desc="\luaescapestring{#2}"})%
}%
}

\newcommand{\key}[2]{#1\addtosort{#1}{#2}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\gdef\printsorted{\directlua{
tblru=tbl or {}

local function ChangingLatinStr(s)
if string.find(s:sub(1, 1), "%a") then
    return "ЯЯЯ" .. s
else return s
end
end

table.sort(tbl, function (a,b) return (ChangingLatinStr(a.abbr) < ChangingLatinStr(b.abbr)) end)

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    tex.print("\string\\printkw{" .. n.abbr .. "}{" .. n.desc .. "}")
end
}
}
\endgroup


\newcommand\printkw[2]{\textbf{#1}~-- #2.\\}

\newcommand{\printkey}{%
\typeout{KW: NOW SHOWING}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}

\noindent\printsorted
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\key{ЯНАО}{Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ}.


\key{LED}{Light emitting diode}.

\key{FET}{Field effect transistor}.

\key{БД}{База данных}.

\key{ЛПР}{Лицо, принимающее решения}.

\key{XML}{Extensible markup language}.

\printkey

\end{document}
```

Comment: You also changed \def to \gdef. It works Thank, @David Carlisle !

Comment: @Youra_P the `\gdef` is just use so that the definition is valid outside the group in `\begingroup ... \endgroup` (that group keeps the category code change local, so that you don't need to actively revert it).